# Does Java Web Start caches resources or ever uses If-Modified-Since?

Tags: java, browser-cache, java-web-start, if-modified-since

A browser can cache resources such as a picture, and sends header with `If-Modified-Since` so a servlet can check and return 304 if it's not modified.

So what about Java Web Start?  Does it ever do this?  I checked that my java web start doesn't have header for `If-Modified-Since` even for the splash screen.  Does that mean Java Web Start doesn't have a cache like a browser?

Comment: JWS does have a cache.  I doubt it is quite like the one used by the browser.